# Como creo una Menu? Python

Tags: python

Cree un menú para registrar usuarios e iniciar sesión, también el menú tendrá la opción de eliminar usuarios, para ello, utilice el nombre de usuario, además para confirmar la eliminación, deberán escribir la contraseña correspondiente de cada usuario.

Inicio sesión.
Registrar usuario
Eliminar usuario.
Salir.

el código de abajo es uno que hice solo que ahora me están pasando listas y me están pidiendo agregar los usuarios en lista para posterior borrarlos a ellos y su contraseña y la verdad no se como hacer que una lista me diga que no tengo ningún dato y me tenga que mandar a la opción 2 que es registrar lo de borrar usuario se que es con un .pop y salir un breck pero no tengo idea de como hacer que el código me reconozca que no tengo ningún usuario

```
opcion = 0
user = 0
usuario1 = None
usuario2 = None
usuario3 = None
contrasena1 = None
contrasena2 = None
contrasena3 = None

while (opcion != 3):
print("1. Iniciar Sesión")
print("2. Registrar Usuario")
print("3. Salir")

try:
    opcion = int(input())

except:
    print("Debe ingresar sólo números")

if (opcion == 1):

    if (user == 0):
        print("Primero debe crear un usuario")

    else:
        var = input("Ingrese ususario: ")

        if (usuario1 == var):
            password = int(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))

            if (password == contrasena1):
                while (opcion != 3):
                    print("1. Realizar LLamada")
                    print("2. Enviar correo electrónico")
                    print("3. Salir")

                    try:
                        opcion = int(input())

                    except:
                        print("Debe ingresar sólo números")

                    if (opcion == 1):
                        numb = int(input("Ingrese telefono: "))

                    while (100000000 > numb or numb > 999999999):
                        print("error al ingresar numero")

                        numb = int(input("Ingrese telefono: "))

                    print("Llamando a ", numb)
                    input("Presione enter para continuar...")

                if (opcion == 2):
                    correo = input("Ingrese correo: ")
                    contador = 0

                    for i in correo:
                        if (i == "@"):
                            contador = contador + 1

                    while (contador != 1):
                        print("error , debe tener 1 y sólo un @")
                        correo = input("Ingrese correo: ")
                        contador = 0

                        for i in correo:
                            if (i == "@"):
                                contador = contador + 1

                    mensaje = input("mensaje: ")
                    print("Enviando mensaje: \n", mensaje, "\nCorreo: ", correo)

        else:
            print("contraseña incorrecta")

        if (usuario2 == var):
            password = int(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))

            if (password == contrasena2):
                print("ingreso")  # luego esto se llamara funciones

            else:
                print("contaseña incorrecta")

        if (usuario3 == var):
            password = int(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))

            if (password == contrasena3):
                print("ingreso")

            else:

                print("contaseña incorrecta")

if (opcion == 2):


    if (user < 3):

        if (user == 0):
            if (opcion == 2):

                if (user < 3):

                    if (user == 0):

                        usuario1 = input("Ingrese nombre de usuario: ")

                        try:

                            contrasena1 = int(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))

                            user = user + 1

                        except:

                            print("Debe ser sólo número")

                    elif (user == 1):

                        usuario2 = input("Ingrese usuario: ")

                        try:

                            contrasena2 = int(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))

                            user = user + 1

                        except:

                            print("Debe ser sólo número")


                    elif (user == 2):

                        usuario3 = input("Ingrese usuario: ")

                        try:

                            contrasena3 = int(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))

                            user = user + 1

                        except:

                            print("Debe ser sólo número")

                    else:

                        print("Máximo de ususarios registrados")
```

Comment: Ya te iba a decir *No se hacen tareas*, bueno te sugiero intentar y luego volver, añadiendo lo que ya has intentado, las listas tienen cosas interesantes :)

Comment: De principio estas pidiendo una forma de crear un menú con todo un sistema de login, y despues preguntas sobre como validar datos en una lista, ¿Cual es el verdadero problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, luego de ver que agregaste codigo y que no buscabas que te hicieran ese menú, trataré de darte respuesta:
guardar usuarios en esas variables (usuario1,usuario2,usuario3) limita la cantidad de usuarios y hacer uso de listas da una solución a esto pero complicará el codigo, la mejor solución que se me ocurre es hacer uso de [diccionarios](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diccionarios-en-python/) donde podras registrar un usuario y relacionarlo con su contraseña (ademas de poder agregar mas información a futuro!).

**así que... solución con diccionarios!:**

**1)** Crear un diccionario vacio:

> ```
> usuarios = {}
> ```

**2)** comprobar si el diccionario esta vacio?:

> ```
> if usuarios == {}:
>     #algo
> ```

**3)** Agregar un usuario nuevo?:

> ```
> usuarios[nombreUsuario] = contra
> #agregara un nuevo elemento con key: numbreUsuario y value: contra
> #por ejemplo: usuario['manuel']='1234'
> #se guardará en el diccionario como: {'manuel':'1234'}
> ```

**4)** Eliminar un usuario en usuarios?:

> ```
> del usuarios[nombreUsuario]
> #eliminará el el usuario y su valor(contraseña)
> #Warning! debes tener cuidado con del porque si no especificas [] eliminara todo el diccionario
> ```

**5)** Comprobar si un usuario ya se encuentra en usuarios?:

> ```
> nombreUsuario in usuario
> #devolvera True o False
> ```

**Ahora.. si realmente debes trabajar con listas entonces deberas hacer lo siguiente:**

**1)** crear dos listas, una para usuarios y otra para cotraseñas:

> ```
> usuarios=[]
> contras=[]
> ```

****2)**** Comprobar si ususarios esta vacio(y a su vez debera estarlo las contraseñas):

> ```
> if (usuarios == [] and contras == []):
>     #lista vacia!
> ```

**3)** Agregar usuario nuevo:

`usuarios+=[nombreUsuario]`

`contras+=[contraUsuario]`

****4)**** eliminar usuario (segun su nombre de usuario dado):

```
> usuario.remove(nombreUsuario)
> #nota: no uses pop a menos que lo que quieras es eliminar el ultimo elemento de la lista (pop()) o un elemento dado su indice
> (pop(indice))
```

**5)** Comprobar si un usuario existe:

> `nombreUsuario in usuarios`

Estos cambios son para el registro de nuevos valores (usuario), el codigo podria ser refactorizado aun mas si en vez de usar tantos if/else usas [funciones](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-4/definiendo-funciones).

Nota: estoy usando citas en vez de formato de codigo porque por algun motivo no cambia el formato.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo, tomare en cuenta tu ayuda